# Eclipse: socks proxy parameter error after jdk 1.7 upgrade

Tags: proxy, java-7, jvm-arguments

I had the following proxy VM args configured in Eclipse for a few months:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=socks.OUR-HOST-SERVER-HERE.com -DsocksProxyPort=1080
```

Following an upgrade to Java 1.7, the following error message appeared:

```
Could not connect to:  : 65181            
java.net.SocketException: SOCKS: Connection not allowed by ruleset
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:553)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.connect(RemoteTestRunner.java:570)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:381)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any idea what went wrong? Are the VM args for proxy different in Java 7?